# Socket.io with React, server-to-client emit call not being received

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm using React with Socket.io and trying to make my component update in real time, so one user can create a new event and it immediately shows up for all users. I've done this before outside of React, and it seems so simple, but I can't get it to work.

Desired behavior: When a user adds a new event, the server sends the new event to the client, where the client sets the new event into the redux store.

Actual behavior: The server emits the event, but the client never receives it. In the network tab, two websocket connections have status 'pending'.

This is my code:

server:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  socket.on('createEvent', async (event, acknowledge) => {

    let err;
    let result;

    // add event to DB
    result = await db.createEvent(event);
    if(!result) err = "An error occured during event creation.";
    acknowledge(err, result);

    console.log('result', result);

    if (result) {
        socket.emit('eventCreated', result);
        console.log('emitted eventCreated');
    }
  });
});
```

Client:

```
componentDidMount () {
   this.getEventsFromDB();

   //listen for new events
   socket.on ('eventCreated', (event) => {
     console.log('hello,', event);
     this.props.dispatch(addEvent({ event }));
   });
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer - I was using `const socket = io()` at the start of each file on the client side where I was using websockets. So each page was getting its own separate socket, which worked just fine until I needed two different pages to have access to the same socket.

I fixed it by instantiating one socket in my main file with my router, and passing it down to each component as a prop or via Redux.